# Disable a specific Button on click in react native

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of buttons on react native (around 3000 buttons) listed on a ListView component.

How do you disable button number 365 on a button click?

Comment: You have to provide some kind of code. There's no way anybody can assist if you don't help us help you.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to disable button number 365 when you click this button or any other button?

Comment: when i click the button 365, it should disable itself

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned a key point here, how do you plan to disable a button? Do you want to disable a button in response to some action or do you want to disable a button by-default? Please specify. So I'm assuming a few things here-

1. You want to disable a button upon some action, you will have to
   maintain state.
2. You have used `TouchableHighlight` or
   `TouchableWithoutFeedback`

Use `rowId` intelligently to disable exact item. populate an array of disaled IDs and accordingly disable that item.

Your render method renders ListView

```
render: function(){
    return(
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => renderItem.bind(this, rowId)}
            style={styles.listView}
        />
    );
},
renderItem: function(id){
    return <Item id={id} enabled={this.state.isEnabled} data={{name: 'foo', details: 'bar'}} />
}
```

Item component will have its own functions and state and props.

```
render: function(){
    return(
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={'#939393'} onPress={this.onPressItem}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
                <Text>{this.props.data.details}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
},
onPressItem: function(){
    if(this.props.enabled){
        //do something
    }
    else{
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies for not elaborating well but you got my point. Basically my issue is re-rendering a row in react-native. For example, i have a like button, i would like to disable like button when i press on it. How do you do that with react native?

Comment: how to disable all buttons except clicked one ... after click happens